What material is this bathroom sink made of?
I’ve encountered a sink in a public restroom that has a very distinct appearance, and I’m curious about the material used in its construction. The sink has a matte, concrete-like texture with small chips and imperfections visible on the surface.
I am not an expert, but I’m a hobbyist familiar with scagliola. I’ve made some small art pieces, and now I want to create something that has a similar texture but is more resistant to outdoor weather conditions. (Probably I am gonna try to put together a sink at home, but I am quite far from that in knowledge: but my enquiry is a start:).) However, I don’t have any experience in architecture or construction, so please explain things with that in mind.
Could you help me identify what material this sink is made of? I’ve included close-up images for reference.
Thank you for any guidance or insights you can offer!




Hi ssheep, perhaps Home Improvement is a more appropriate site for your questions, as users there might be more familiar with building materials.

Concrete sinks are actually a thing.

Looks like an answer...

It is concrete. Looks like it was precast and mortared in place but since it is concrete one could cast it into any shape. A whole bathroom could be poured in place if you wanted. On a smaller scale there are premix bags where all you add is water and mix to get the concrete.
There is a large variety of concrete products out there so it is not clear which brand or subclass of concrete this is. Some mixes embed fiberglass into the concrete for making practical things like sinks and furniture because it adds strength and reduces weight. However that does not seem to be the case here as it looks like regular every day concrete.

I concur, it looks like regular run of the mill precast concrete. especially that crack. The way that it's crumbling around the edge says that it's definitely not resin, ceramic or plastic.

Yes, I think it's concrete too. I'm guessing it has one or more additives to make it's surface a little more unique than most industrial concretes.  I've examined these closely before, and they don't feel like most industrial concretes.  They could employ a special finishing technique as well.
